# Using String.contain(number) to find out same number in a string

Tags: java

I am stuck on this for a while:

I want to get a string (named b) and match it with an element from a String list, containing many numbers. For example:

```
if (list.get(i).split(";")[1].split("\t")[7].contains(b))
```

So I used this:

```
ArrayList<String> ids = remove(list);

String matches []="532","533","534","535","5","537","538","539","540","541"};

for (String b : matches){

    for (String element : ids) {

        if(element.contains(b))
            System.out.println(element);

    }            
}
```

But when it gets to the match b=5, it shows all values that contain 5 in it and not just the element "5".

I have used `.equal` but that does not show anything. Can someone help?

Comment: trim the elements before using `equals` ? It's hard to guess the problem when we only have half the test data...

Comment: Show us your sample data or a test

Comment: its simple, if a string contains `533` then it also contains `5`  as well as `3` , what you need is to reformulate your code logic, probably good idea to see how your Strings in `ids` are.

Comment: incomplete example. should be Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable.

Comment: list has data like this "3.981935961313284 ; 212 C6 A A 117.441 -8.086 7.564 7;  2191 HZ2 LYS B 121.258 -7.468 6.613 95"

Comment: and ids have "533-519, U-LEU
533-435, U-PRO
533-434, U-LYS
533-492, C-LYS
534-492, C-ARG"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a potential issue with white characters in your id list elements. Perhaps you could try this variation on your code:

```
ArrayList<String> ids = remove(list);

String matches [] = new String[] {"532","533","534","535","5","537","538","539","540","541"};

for (String b : matches) {

    for (String element : ids) {
        if(element.indexOf(b) > 0 && 
        !Character.isDigit(element.charAt(element.indexOf(b)-1)) && 
        (element.indexOf(b) >= element.length()-b.length() || 
        !Character.isDigit(element.charAt(element.indexOf(b)+b.length())))) {
            System.out.println(element);
        } else {
            System.out.println(">"+element"<-->"+b+"<");
        }
    }            
}
```

This way you could check the rejected elements and see what the difference between `b` and the item you're trying to match with. The `trim` I added may be enough to help, and if not - you can view the differences and see how to best fix it.

Comment: >C-ASN
532-519<-->532<
>C-HIS
532-520<-->532<

Comment: this is the output i got

Comment: Do you want to find the 532 within C-ASN 532-519? For you, the match should have been positive in this case?

Comment: yes if i use contain then it works on it but when  i want to find 5 it show all the values containing 5 like 532

Comment: Ok, I changed the example in this question to be more specific to the pattern you expect - see if it gets better results. If it works for some and not for others, let me know. If it works well - I'd appreciate it if you could accept this answer by clicking on the check mark in the left, making it green.

Comment: >C-ASN
532-519<-->532<
>C-HIS
532-520<-->532<
>U-ARG
533-5219<-->532<

Comment: I made a better qualifier, added to the answer. Mind trying it out? @Walizebkhan

Comment: Final update added - I tested it for various end cases. It should work.

Comment: @Walizebkhan, thanks for accepting the answer! I'm happy it worked well for you. If you like, you could also up-vote the answer by clicking on the little arrow up next to the answer. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see Your **id** is in the format of `"U-LEU 533-435"`

```
for(String element : ids){
       String temp = element.replaceAll("\\s", "-");
       String[] firstSplit = temp.split("-");
       for(String s : firstSplit){
          if(s.equals(b)){
            System.out.println(element);
          }
       }

 }
```

If all your Ids are following same format, you could try this out :)